# Tolerance on SMD Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

I'm searching for some polarized surface mount device capacitors on lcsc.com and notice that they only have tolerances of \$20\%\$ tolerance devices in their catalog for this type of SMD device whereas the through hole counter parts have much lower tolerances. Is this normal for this type of device? My inherent feeling is that a \$20\%\$ tolerance is rather large.

edit:

The capacitors will be used in a Li-Po charge management circuit as shown below:

[image: Li-Po charge circuit]

Comment: +/- 20% is fairly standard for electrolytic capacitors, whether surface mount or through hole, certainly panasonic have the same tolerance on the smd and through hole parts for the same family.

Comment: These are generally designed for a purpose where this tolerance is quite normal, although from memory I would have said the most I saw was -5/+20

Comment: Do you think it would be safe to assume that a data sheet application circuit would operate fine with a 20% tolerance? There is nothing in the application circuit that explicitly states tolerance of components.

Comment: What are the capacitors used for?

Comment: @Colin I have updated the post with the schematic. They'll be used in a li-po battery charging circuit.

Comment: If you're referring to Cout and Cin, it's a little confusing, they're shown as polarized on the schematic, but then section 9.2.2 of the datasheet says to "Use standard value 10 μF, 25 V, X5R, ±20% ceramic capacitor (that is, Panasonic 1206 ECJ-3YB1E106M" I would go with that ceramic part for both.

Comment: Not directly related but.. 10uF at low voltages, at least in my use cases, using MLCC has been making a lot more sense than electrolytics.

Comment: @Colin thanks, this is extremely helpful. I don't see any 0.1uF electrolytics either so I assume ceramics should be fine. Another question - the 2 cell application in this data sheet uses the same values as for the single cell which is based on the design paramaters at the start of that section. I take it that if I want to use a 2 cell 7.4v battery with 12v input voltage I will need to use the design equations to work out different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's completely normal. Electrolytic capacitors (and also typically high capacitance MLCC capacitors) are not usually designed into applications where tight tolerance is important. For a filter capacitor -20/+80% is sometimes just fine.

You should use an MLCC ceramic capacitor, but keep in mind that the tolerance can be worse than 20%, and almost always in the wrong direction- down, when you take voltage coefficient into account. Very small (physically) capacitors operated at close to the rated voltage are usually the worst in that regard.

**Ceramic caps are what is recommended** in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24109.pdf). Ceramic capacitors have lower ESR (they are "better") but that may cause problems in some situations, but in this case there are no issues from ESR.

---

The datasheet says (for a particular configuration):

> Use standard value 10 μF, 25 V, X5R, ±20% ceramic capacitor (that is, Panasonic 1206 ECJ-3YB1E106M

If you were to subsitute a [Murata 0402](https://psearch.en.murata.com/capacitor/product/GRM155C80J106ME11%23.pdf) 10uF/6.3V cap (adequate for a single 4.2V cell) the tolerance is given as +/-20% but typically at 4.2V the capacitance would be less than 3uF, and probably less than 2uF if you take temperature and bias and tolerance into account. So +/-20% is a bit of a dream. Maybe at room temperature and with 0V across it, plus they can actually make the capacitors much more accurately than +/-20% under set conditions so they're actually cutting it on the low side (typically 9uF at room temperature with 0V bias).